# Can I mount a share and enable the user_xattr mount option?

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, fstab, xattr

I have a ext4 drive that is mounted using `defaults` mount options. It is a RedHat Enterprise Linux version 6.5, 64 bits. I can call `lsattr` on any file on that server.

I need to share that drive with 3 other servers, all running the same version of RHEL. And I need to read extended attributes with `lsattr` on any of the 4 servers.

When mounting the drive with this command:

```
mount -t nfs s1.example.com:/a/b /a/b -o rw,sync,hard,intr,user_xattr
```

I tells me `user_xattr` is incorrect:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

How can I mount an exported drive and keep the ability of calling `lsattr` on those files?

*How I share the disk is not important, as long as lsattr works. Those RHEL are actually Virtual Boxes on Windows 7, so even Virtual Box Shared Folder (vboxsf) would do. I tried, didn't work.*

Answer (score 2):

NFS support for xattr has just been added to Kernel 5.9